# Correct way to encode JSON and store in MYSQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I'm encoding my javascript arrays using JSON.stringify in javascript before sending them to php via AJAX to store in mysql (btw - I don't need to query the data, just store it).

my example array (1 item) after $_POST looks like

```
[\"Shaun Thomson\"]
```

and after mysql_real_escape_string it looks like

```
[\\\"Shaun Thomson\\\"]
```

so ends up in mysql like

```
[\"Shaun Thomson\"]
```

What's the correct way to do this so it ends up (safely) in mysql like

```
["Shaun Thomson"]
```

?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It *looks* like you want to unescape your "my example array" and use an SQL parameter to send it to the database. [MySQL: Working with Parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html).

Comment: Do it as explained in the [manual page](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). MySQL couldn't care less about where your data comes from.

Comment: @Andrew - thanks. Does this mean I should JSON encode on the javascript side? Just send it as an array to php and encode it PHP?

Comment: I assumed that your "my example array" is what you received in the PHP code. If you use an SQL parameter to store it in the database, there is no need to escape it for that operation.

Answer (score 0):

instead of mysql_real_escape_string, try using [`stripslashes`](https://www.php.net/stripslashes).

Comment: Thanks Palpatim - but don't I need mysql_real_escape_string to make it safe?